# LocalDateTime.parse(yyyMMddHHmmssSSS, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS") error

Tags: java, milliseconds, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

Why doesn't it work?   ... 1) is works, but 2) occurs DateTimeParseException.

**# 1**

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS");
LocalDateTime dt1 = LocalDateTime.parse("20211211134321.221", formatter1);
```

**# 2**

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse("20211211134321221", formatter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Bug, fixed in Java 9+

Per the comments, it seems that such code runs successfully in some earlier versions of Java 8 but fails in other later versions of Java 8.

Apparently due to a bug, [JDK-8031085](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085), fixed in Java 9+.

---

Here is my reformatted version of your code.

```java
DateTimeFormatter fx = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS" ); 
LocalDateTime x = LocalDateTime.parse( "20211211134321.221" , fx );
System.out.println( "x = " + x ) ;

DateTimeFormatter fy = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS" ); 
LocalDateTime y = LocalDateTime.parse( "20211211134321221" , fy );
System.out.println( "y = " + y ) ;
```

When run in Java 12, as seen [on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/HOPHVP).

```
x = 2021-12-11T13:43:21.221
y = 2021-12-11T13:43:21.221
```

Comment: Thank you! My Java version is 1.8.0_301. 

 It runs well in 1.8.0_51 version.
you can see here => (https://ideone.com/G6P3Yg)

But when it runs with error in 1.8.0_66 
you can see here =>  (jdoodle.com/ia/jW2)
 

Thank you Basil Bourque.

Comment: @LindaLee The current version of Java 8 is 312.

Comment: Any possible workarounds in case we still want to stick with Java1.8? Thanks.

Comment: @vmorusu Sure… do the parsing yourself. Grab the first four characters, parse as an integer for the year.  Grab next two characters, parse another integer as month. Repeat for each part. [Assemble the integers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of(int,int,int,int,int,int,int)) into a `LocalDateTime`.